# Phpword $objWriter attributes

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) in a project.

I am trying to find out some information about the attributes that go with the `$objWriter`:

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
```

Specifically, what is the 'Word2007' used for at the end? I have tried searching `$objWriter` but can't locate any info. I have tried replacing it with 'Word2013' or 'Word2016' but I get:

> "Word2016" is not a valid writer. in wamp...\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\IOFactory.php on line 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter is for the type of document you're creating a writer for. There are 5 allowed types:

1. 'ODText'
2. 'RTF'
3. 'Word2007'
4. 'HTML'
5. 'PDF'

You can see this in the code for the IOFactory class:

```
public static function createWriter(PhpWord $phpWord, $name = 'Word2007')
{
    /**
     * Notice the allowed names in the array here.
     */
    if ($name !== 'WriterInterface' && !in_array($name, array('ODText', 'RTF', 'Word2007', 'HTML', 'PDF'), true)) {
        throw new Exception("\"{$name}\" is not a valid writer.");
    }
    $fqName = "PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\{$name}";
    return new $fqName($phpWord);
}
```

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/IOFactory.php

If you want to support a later MS Word document format, you will need to implement your own writer that `extends AbstractWriter implements WriterInterface`. However, at this time, [there are no later formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word#Binary_formats_.28Word_97.E2.80.932007.29) yet created. (Note that Word 2007 the *format* is different from the application version.)

Comment: Thanks Don. Very helpful. My test documents seem to load up in 2016 ok. Though this makes me slightly uneasy...

Comment: @maxelcat Why does it make you uneasy? As stated in my answer, Word2016 uses the Word2007 format. Word formats are not the same as Word app versions.

Comment: I think I didn't quite understand - so thank you for clearing it up! :-)